# Reduce is called several times with the same key in mongodb map-reduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I'm trying to run map reduce on mongodb in mongo shell. For some reason, in the reduce phase, I get several calls for the same key (instead of single one), so I get wrong results.
I'm not an expert in this domains, so maybe I'm doing some stupid mistake. Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

This is my small example:

I'm creating 10000 documents:

```
var i = 0;
db.docs.drop();
while (i < 10000) {
    db.docs.insert({text:"line " + i,index:i});
    i++;
}
```

Then I'm doing map-reduce based on module 10 (so I except to get 1000 in each "bucket")

```
db.docs.mapReduce(
    function() { 
       emit(this.index%10,1);
    },
    function(key,values) {
       return values.length;
    },
    {
    out : {inline : 1}
    }
);
```

However, as results I get the following:

```
{
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "value" : 21
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "value" : 21
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "value" : 21
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "value" : 21
        },
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "value" : 21
        },
        {
            "_id" : 5,
            "value" : 21
        },
        {
            "_id" : 6,
            "value" : 21
        },
        {
            "_id" : 7,
            "value" : 21
        },
        {
            "_id" : 8,
            "value" : 21
        },
        {
            "_id" : 9,
            "value" : 21
        }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 76,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 10000,
        "emit" : 10000,
        "reduce" : 500,
        "output" : 10
    },
    "ok" : 1,
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Map/Reduce is essentially a recursive operation. In particular, the [documented requirements for the `reduce` function](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#mapreduce-reduce-cmd) include the following statement:

> MongoDB can invoke the `reduce` function more than once for the same key. In this case, the previous output from the `reduce` function for that key will become one of the input values to the next `reduce` function invocation for that key.

Therefore, you have to expect that the input is merely the number that was counted by a previous invocation. The following code does that by actually adding the values:

```
db.docs.mapReduce(
    function() { emit(this.index % 10, 1); }, 
    function(key,values) { return Array.sum(values); }, 
    { out : {inline : 1} } );
```

Now, the `emit(key, 1)` makes more sense in a way, because `1` is no longer just any number used to fill the array, but its value is considered.

As a sidenote, note how dangerous this is: For a smaller dataset, the correct result might have been given by accident, because the engine decided a parallelization wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Yeah, map/reduce is a bit like XML: It looks simple, but somehow it's confusing and has a bunch of pitfalls :/